How to disable HTTPS redirection in TestCafe
I'm trying to run a test on testcafe, but I'm having a problem. I understand that this is happening because testcafe forces redirection from http to https. On the development stand, the site only works on http. Could you please tell me if there is any option to prevent forced redirection? If there is, where can I specify it?
I enter image description heretried setting the baseUrl property in my TestCafe configuration file, but it didn't work either.
My code:
    import { RequestMock } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Simple Test`
    .page `about:blank`;

test('Navigate to page', async t => {

    await t.wait(2000);

    await t.navigateTo("http://dop.ds73.dev.gelicon.biz/");

    await t.wait(2000);

});

Answer:
Running tests in:
 - Chrome 130.0.0.0 / Windows 10

 Simple Test
 × Navigate to page

   1) Failed to load the page at "https://dop.ds73.dev.gelicon.biz/".
      Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the "retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute this test.
      You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".

      Error details:
      Error: ConnectionRefused

      Browser: Chrome 130.0.0.0 / Windows 10

          5 |
          6 |test('Navigate to page', async t => {
          7 |
          8 |    await t.wait(2000);
          9 |
       > 10 |    await t.navigateTo("http://dop.ds73.dev.gelicon.biz/");
         11 |
         12 |    await t.wait(2000);
         13 |
         14 |});

         at <anonymous> (C:\projects\testcafe\testcafedemo\tests\test.js:10:13)
         at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\projects\testcafe\testcafedemo\tests\test.js:1:40)
         at _next (C:\projects\testcafe\testcafedemo\tests\test.js:1:40)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I included a code sample.
